# How to determine process which makes DNS Request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, troubleshooting, malware, auditd, botnet

I have a server on AWS, GuardDuty started send me notifications:

```
*** "type":"Backdoor:EC2/C&CActivity.B!DNS",
*** {"domain":"libcurl.so","protocol":"UDP","blocked":false}
*** is querying a domain name associated with a known Command & Control server. ***
```

I've checked the server with all possible security tools and nothing found.
With `tcpdump -A` I saw that my server send such kind of request about this domain.
I have turned on auditd. But nothing strange was found.

My question is, how to determine, which process exactly send this request?

Comment: If the server is compromised, you can't trust that something like `auditd` will work - it's already a lost cause. Read [how do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) - but first, shut the server off so it stops attacking people.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer can't help solve the problem and do not answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: It may not be the answer you *want* to hear, but it **is** the answer.

Comment: Ok, we can suggest that the link above is the answer. But major question was: how do determine the process, which send DNS request? Any ideas?

Comment: @kbu You'll need to shut the server down, mount its filesystem to a new, uncompromised server, and start analyzing things. You'll first want to ask yourself if you regularly patch your servers (and any software on it, like web apps).

Comment: This is a mail server and all patches installed when they are available. Nothing unnecessary is installed, all ports and daemons monitored

Comment: Your next step will probably be the auth log, weak passwords, or compromise of a machine used to administrate the server, like your own computer.

Comment: Thank you all for your very helpful comments. The process was found with: auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a0=2 -F a1\&=2 -S socket -k SOCKET

Comment: This was a pyzor. Since a stopped communication with pyzor any requests to libcurl were stopped.

Comment: Another source of false positives can be `sshd` if port 22 is open and `UseDNS=yes`, which is the default on many Linux images.
In this case **any** ssh scanner from a suspicious domain will trigger the `Backdoor:EC2/C&CActivity.B!DNS` finding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid with normal packet captures there is no way of identifying the PID from the packets, because all you can see is what port the packet was sent from.

You can use netstat to identify who is using that port but DNS takes millisecondes so you have to be very lucky.

Systemtap can be used to find which process sent udp packets to dns using the example systemtap script :https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/network/who_sent_it.stp

Last solution provided by AWS : If you are unable to identify and stop unauthorized activity on your EC2 instance, we recommend that you terminate the compromised EC2 instance and replace it with a new instance as needed.

Comment: "to find which process sent udp packets to dns" while remembering that DNS uses TCP as well...

Answer (score 2):

Official answer from AWS:

```
The GuardDuty team has confirmed this to be a false positive. The domain "libcurl.so" has been removed from the source threat intelligence list.
```

FYI: Passwords are not weak and other best practices were realized. OSSEC, Tripwire and other stuff is on the server.

Comment: Side question: are you getting these notifications every 6 hours?  In one of my environments, I have this same `Backdoor:EC2/C&CActivity.B!DNS` rule firing every 6 hours on one instance for a different (and similarly harmless) domain, even though the DNS queries to that domain are no longer occurring, confirmed by wireshark -- as if the incident is somehow "stuck" in Guard Duty.  I'm curious if you are perhaps unable to capture it with tcpdump for the same reason.  The console shows the last incident was weeks ago, but the events continue to fire.

Comment: Yes, it was every 6 hours

Comment: Thank you.  Aside from whether `libcurl.so` is a false positive or not (this is subjective and I am inclined to disagree with that assessment -- the site seems harmless, but *accessing this site* could have been a sign of failing a penetration test because you are making a query that you should not have made) I am curious whether you will continue to get these notifications. 
 There may be a bug in Guard Duty, continuing to notify when nothing is actually continuing to happen.  No response on the official forum, as of now: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=291364&tstart=0

Comment: I will check the system with systemtap and let you know about results

Comment: All requests to libcurl.so from amavis